# Open directories in interaction with a Shapefile

Tags: qgis, python

I am trying to write a python code whose purpose is to open windows directories corresponding to the communes I select in a "common" Shape layer (with Qgis software).
I specify that the common layer contains a column X with the paths to the directories of the communes (example of the path: `V: / 02_doc / commune1 /`)

Here is my current code. It does not work as intended (it opens ... the windows directory "'my documents"

```
import os
X = os.path.dirname( unicode( qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri() ) )
os.system("explorer " + "[%"X"%]")
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
```

---

This code is used to indicate a single path and point on when I click on the layer.

```
import subprocess
layer = iface.activeLayer()
x = layer.source()
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,' + x)
```

That's not what I want.

---

`with this code:

```
import os
X = os.path.dirname( unicode( qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri() ) )
os.system("explorer "+posplu)
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
```

There is a change, when I click on my layer in Qgis, I point the directory where my layer is.

That's not what I want.

My layer contains an x ​​column.
The latter includes paths pointing repertory directories to cities. I would like to click on a city A and open the directory A, on a city B and open the directory B.

---

I found

```
import os layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer() import subprocess subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select r,"[% X %]"')
```

x is the column containing directory paths fcka

Comment: Please edit your question to include a output of printing X. In a test on my system, a typo in my path ("Downlaods" vs "Downloads") resulted in opening "My Documents".

Answer (score 1):

This line isn't valid python syntax:

```
os.system("explorer " + "[%"X"%]")
```

if I test with:

```
X="some path"
print("explorer " + "[%"X"%]")
```

I get:

```
>>> print("explorer " + "[%"X"%]")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("explorer " + "[%"X"%]")
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm not sure what the exact syntax is to run explorer in windows, but maybe you just want to concatenate the `X` with the rest of the string:

```
>>> print("explorer " + "[%"+X+"%]")
explorer [%some path%]
```

If its just the path for the argument then maybe quote it:

```
>>> print("explorer \""+X+"\"")
explorer "some path"
```

Its a good practice to construct and print the string you are making before running `os.system` on it, for debugging purposes:

```
cmd = "explorer "+X
print("cmd is ",cmd)
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: This is a good point Spacedman. Highlighting just one section for fcka: try changing `os.system("explorer " + "[%"X"%]")` to `os.system(cmd)` with an earlier stage building `cmd = "explorer " + '"{}"'.format(X)`  In other words, if the line above created X = `c:\users\username\Downloads\My Folder`, then `cmd` should translate to `'explorer "c:\users\username\Downloads\My Folder"'`.  Currently the brackets and percentages may be making the path invalid, causing it to open Documents instead.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar a while ago but used [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) instead:

```
import subprocess
layer = iface.activeLayer()
x = layer.source()
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,' + x)
```